# Firebase notification in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, firebase, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm implementing Firebase in a Xamarin Forms application.
I use the Rest API for the database.

Is there a way to register the notification token using the REST API?
Write code for both iOS and Android that extracts the token and posts to a REST API endpoint?

Or perhaps there is a better solution for Firebase notifications in Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to register the notification token using the REST API? Write code for both iOS and Android that extracts the token and posts to a REST API endpoint?

In Xamarin.form it does not provide the cross platform API to push notification. But you can achieve push notification in each platform. Take android as an example :

```
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService {
        public override void onTokenRefresh() {
            // Get updated InstanceID token.
            String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
            // send Instance ID token to your app server.
            sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
        }
        private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
            //implement this method to send token to your app server 
        }
    }
```

In the `sendRegistrationToServer`function you can posts the token to a REST API endpoint.
Do not forget to register the service to android manifest.

[Android firebase guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/)

For IOS platform please refer this [document guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote_notifications_in_ios/)